# Why does the characteristic need to be 3?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, field-theory

[image]

and this is the solution given

[image]

Why do we need the characteristic to be 3? Why wouldn't this work if over $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{9Z}$?

Comment: I dont understand why we need the bit from "This happens precisely when the characteristic...." onwards

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.

Comment: Another way of saying it --- there is no such thing as a field of composite characteristic. If the characteristic isn't zero, then it's a prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $9$ to be the same as $0$ in the base field. As a field contains no zero divisors and $3\times 3 = 9$ which is $0$, we must also have $3$ equal to $0$. This is only true in a field of characteristic $3$. An example of a field of characteristic $3$ is $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Any other field of characteristic $3$ would also be a suitable answer, but $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field (for example, $3\times 3 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$, but $3 \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: forgot that $\mathbb{Z/pZ}$ is a field iff $p$ is a prime